# Django book details with different form and html template

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

i have some question about a DJANGO framework book blog details example .My problem is i have a book list in Django template using something like this `{% url 'book_details' value.slug_title %}`.My problem is for different book details i have a different Django form and different HTML template .i build a snippet code and work fine ,but i dont like this code way ,i would like to propose a different code way to take correct results.

here the code :

```
def blog_details(request,slug):

    data = get_object_or_404(app_descript, slug_title=slug)
    if str(data.title) == 'name 1':
        if request.method=='POST':

             .......................

        return render(request, 'details/name1.html', {'data': data})


    elif str(data.title) == 'name 2':
        if request.method=='POST':
            ...............................


        return render(request, 'details/name2.html', {'data': data})
        
    elif str(data.title) == 'name 3':
        if request.method=='POST':
            .................


        return render(request, 'details/name3.html', {'data': data})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this snippet?

```
class BookBaseView(View):
    template_name = 'details/base.html'
    form_class = None
    
    def get(self, request, slug):
        book = get_object_or_404(Book, slug_title=slug)
        form = self.form_class(instance=book)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'book': book, 'form': form})
        
    def post(self, request, slug):
        book = get_object_or_404(Book, slug_title=slug)
        form = self.form_class(request.POST, instance=book)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # handle successful form submission
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'book': book, 'form': form})

class Book1View(BookBaseView):
    template_name = 'details/book1.html'
    form_class = Book1Form

class Book2View(BookBaseView):
    template_name = 'details/book2.html'
    form_class = Book2Form

class Book3View(BookBaseView):
    template_name = 'details/book3.html'
    form_class = Book3Form
```

**URL**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('book1/<slug:slug>/', Book1View.as_view(), name='book1_details'),
    path('book2/<slug:slug>/', Book2View.as_view(), name='book2_details'),
    path('book3/<slug:slug>/', Book3View.as_view(), name='book3_details'),
    # other URL patterns for your application
]
```

Comment: look great and i need to test it ,my question how to use hyperlink '{% url 'book_details' value.slug_title %}' ?

Comment: Try: `<a href="{% url 'book_details' value.slug_title %}">Book Details</a>`